# How to express "teeth are not white because they don't brush their teeth often" in everyday English?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> [stained](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stained?q=stained) adjective  /steɪnd/  /steɪnd/ ​ (often in compounds) covered
>   with stains or marked with a stain
>
> My dress was stained.
>
> paint-stained jeans
>
> The sheets were old and stained.
>
> The shirt was heavily stained with blood.

Say, your children don't brush their teeth often and that makes their teeth "**a little dark or black**".

**What should we say?**

-***Your teeth are stained. You need to brush them more often.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native British English speaker, then your example sounds absolutely fine, and stained seems like the correct word to use.

For reference then at least one major toothpaste manufacturer [appears to agree](https://www.colgate.com/en-gb/products/toothpaste/colgate-max-white-expert-complete-anti-stain).